# A position with a choice between checkmate and perpetual check

Tags: checkmate, problems, master-games, perpetual

For some odd reason I'm searching for a game, or rather a position, where one player can force a win via checkmate (can be check in n, where n is any number), but they can also force a draw via perpetual check (again, maybe the perpetual check comes about a few steps later, but the player has an assured path to it).

A real, historical game would be a bonus, and a game between two skilled players will be even better. But constructed positions, even weak ones, will be appreciated, too.

Comment: very odd reason - there are millions of such games - nearly any game played till mate - any game where Q+K mating K fits this at nearly any point, same for R+K Vs K; N+B+K Vs K - there is forced mate or forced perpetual or if you wish forced stalemate  - what a point really spending time on this - go to your local chess organization - they will provide you with scoresheets of thousands of such games, because lower level amateurs often play till checkmate - you can choose any position you like from thousands...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one game which should match your request (Swiderski, Rudolf vs. Nimzowitsch, Aaron):

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
    
1.c4 e6 2.d4 d5 3.Nc3 Nf6 4.Bg5 Nbd7 5.e3 c6 6.Nf3 Be7 7.Qc2 O-O 8.Rd1 Re8 9.Bd3 dxc4 10.Bxc4 Nd5 11.Bxe7 Qxe7 12.O-O b5 13.Bxd5 cxd5 14.Nxb5 Ba6 15. Qa4 Bxb5 16.Qxb5 Reb8 17.Qe2 a5 18.Rc1 Qd8 19.Rc3 a4 20.Rfc1 Qa5 21.Rc7 Nb6 22.R1c5 Qb4 23.a3 Qb3 24.Ng5 Qa2 25.h3 Rf8 26.Kh2 h6 27.Nxe6 Rfc8 28. Qf3 Rf8 29.Qg3 g6 30.Qxg6+ fxg6 31.Rg7+ Kh8 32.Rcc7
```

In the ending position white has a forced mate, e.g.:

```
[FEN "r4r1k/2R3R1/1n2N1pp/3p4/p2P4/P3P2P/qP3PPK/8 b - - 3 1"]

1... Nd7 2. Rcxd7 Rf7 3. Rdxf7 Qxb2 4. Rh7+ Kg8 5. Rfg7#
```

Alternatively, he can force a draw, e.g:

```
[FEN "r4r1k/2R3R1/1n2N1pp/3p4/p2P4/P3P2P/qP3PPK/8 b - - 3 1"]

1... Nd7 2. Rcxd7 Rf7 3. Rdxf7 Qxb2 4. Rh7+ Kg8 5. Rhg7 Kh8 6. Rh7+ Kg8 7. Rhg7 Kh8
```

Probably any game ending in a [Blind Swine Mate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkmate_pattern#Blind_swine_mate) would work.

Comment: I cannot upvote, because of my low reputation, but thank you so much!

Comment: You can accept the answer, by clicking the check mark, if it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

very typical example, this position happened millions of times in chess history:

```
k7/3Q4/1K6/8/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1
```

1. Qb7#, 1. Qc7 Stalemate, 1.Qc6 can start perpetual - just be careful - don't checkmate your opponent by accident :)

Just wondering - if this is really worth studying, but you get what you ask for ...